# What does "the take-away" in this text mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> After four days of increasing complaints from citizens across Houston, the city's Public Works Department finally posted some answers on its website. A spokesman told Local 2 the earthy or musty smell and the taste of dirt is from two naturally occurring compounds: MIB and geosmin, sometimes produced by seasonal algae blooms. **The take-away** ? The city says they are safe and the water is fine to drink.
>   <sub>Source: [City of Houston: Water is safe to drink, use](http://www.click2houston.com/news/city-of-houston-water-is-safe-to-drink-use/26643998)</sub>

Does it mean to "summarize"?

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding, "to 'summarize'", is quite close/correct.

This question should be answerable by dictionaries, but I think it may not be very obvious because of the spelling, and *take away* is usually used as a (phrasal) verb.

Here is its definition given in Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[takeaway](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/takeaway)**
>   <sup>noun [countable]</sup>
>   3. an important piece of information to remember from a meeting, presentation etc
>   *This could be the most important takeaway from today’s Fed announcement.*